# Improving performance of Vue.js application

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In our application, there is large set of data (json ~ 630KB) getting populated which consumes around 219.28 MB of JavaScript memory displayed in chrome task manager.

It loads the data from the api and uses vuex to store the data and generates the menu recursively.

Since it is a big application, I mimicked the same behaviour with a sample vue.js application by loading 100000 records to understand how the memory utilization works.

Each time "Run test" is clicked, 200 MB memory is consumed in the task manager and is not released until so much time even if the page is refreshed.

I tried to use "beforeDestroy" hook to clear the object from vuex but it is not working. I would like to know if the data itself is causing the slow performance or any other improvements can be done.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myApp">
        <button @click="setCounterModule()">Counter</button>
        <button @click="setCustomersModule">Customers</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div>
            <button-counter v-if="currentModule=='counter'"></button-counter>
            <customers v-else></customers>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
    <script src="vuex.js"></script>
    <script>
    Vue.component('button-counter', {
        data: function () {
            return {
                count: 0
            }
        },
        template: '<button v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>'
    });

    Vue.component('customers', {
        computed: {
            customers() {
                return store.state.customers
            }
        },
        template: '<div><button @click="testMe" :disabled="loading">Run Test</button><div v-for="c in customers">{{ c.name }}</div></div>',
        data: function() {
            return {
                loading: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            testMe: function () {
                this.loading = true;
                let customers = [];
                for (var i=0; i < 100000; i++) {
                    let customer = {'name': 'John' +i, 'address': 'Addr' + i};
                    customers.push(customer);
                }
                store.commit('assignCustomers', customers);
                this.loading = false;
            }
        },
        beforeDestroy() {
            // console.log('vuex destroyed');
            // store.commit('assignCustomers', null);
        }
    });

    const store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            customers: null
        },
        mutations: {
            assignCustomers (state, customers) {
               state.customers = customers;
            }
        }
    });
    var app =  new Vue( {
        el: "#myApp",
        data: function() {
            return {
                currentModule: "counter"
            }
        },
        methods: {
            setCounterModule: function() {
                this.currentModule = "counter";
            },
            setCustomersModule: function() {
                this.currentModule = "customers";
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the data need to be reactive? If not, it could help to "freeze" the objects, see https://vuedose.tips/tips/improve-performance-on-large-lists-in-vue-js. Likely, the memory will still not be released, but it might be less anyway.

Comment: It is still 200 MB+ increase in memory consumption in actual application but when I have the done the same in test application, it is  ~100 MB increase in subsequent requests reduced from ~200 MB. In actual application, it has many individual complements like icons for menu sub components, not sure if they are getting disposed of. Any other approaches you know of ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're building exactly that requires you to have all of this data in the store, but filtering it down before adding it to the store might help to keep things snappy.

Comment: I guess its not the store data, the menu item component is taking time. It consists of icons for each item, when I removed the icon, it consumes 100 mb now. Is there a way to opitmize the dom elements generation or rendering

Comment: @Sunny are you able to partition/paginate the data on the server side, let's say get 100 records isntead of 100000?

Comment: Nope, it is not a option since it's a side menu accordion with collapsed panes that doesn't run down the page height, and we need all panes to be loaded at once.